# string array inside of string

Tags: android, arrays, string

how can I put an array where soundID is at, and be recognized by android/java?

String filename="(SoundID)"+".ogg";
         string;

hope theres a way, thanks

Comment: what is soundID? how is it declared? - Am I missing that?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is syntactically impossible in Java, sorry.